# Error "The number of variables must match the number of parameters in the prepared statement" al hacer un SELECT en una sentencia preparada

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy haciendo un sistema que busca productos en la DB, tengo un problema en mi código al hacer una sentencia preparada SELECT. Cuando intento ejecutar una consulta, me aparece

> "Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: The number of variables must match the number of parameters in the prepared statement".

Verifiqué que la cantidad y el tipo de variables coincidan con los parámetros de la consulta. Incluso intenté agregar y quitar parámetros, pero el error persiste. Agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan dar para resolver este error.

Mi codigo:

```
<?php
include '../db/db.php';

if (isset($_GET["s"])) {
    $searchTerm = $_GET["s"];

    $minPrice = 0;
    $maxPrice = 1000000;
    $condition = "nuevo";
    $orderBy = "relevante";
    $region = "all";

    if (isset($_GET["min-price"])) {
        $minPrice = (int) $_GET["min-price"];
    }
    if (isset($_GET["max-price"])) {
        $maxPrice = (int) $_GET["max-price"];
    }
    if (isset($_GET["condition"]) && in_array($_GET["condition"], ["nuevo", "usado"])) {
        $condition = $_GET["condition"];
    }
    if (isset($_GET["order-by"]) && in_array($_GET["order-by"], ["relevante", "mayor-precio", "menor-precio"])) {
        $orderBy = $_GET["order-by"];
    }
    if (isset($_GET["region"]) && in_array($_GET["region"], $regiones)) {
        $region = $_GET["region"];
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE precio BETWEEN ? AND ? AND condicion = ?";

    if ($region != "all") {
        $sql .= " AND id_region = (SELECT id FROM Regiones WHERE nombre = ?)";
    }

    if ($orderBy == "mayor-precio") {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY precio DESC";
    } elseif ($orderBy == "menor-precio") {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY precio ASC";
    }

    if (!empty($searchTerm)) {
        $searchTerm = "%$searchTerm%";
        $sql .= " AND (titulo LIKE ? OR descripcion LIKE ?)";
    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    if ($stmt) {
        if (!empty($searchTerm)) {
            $stmt->bind_param("iisss", $minPrice, $maxPrice, $condition, $region, $searchTerm);
        } else {
            $stmt->bind_param("iiss", $minPrice, $maxPrice, $condition, $region);
        }

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "<h2>Resultados</h2>";
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<h3>" . $row["titulo"] . "</h3>";
                echo "<p>" . $row["descripcion"] . "</p>";
                echo "<p>Precio: $" . number_format($row["precio"], 0, ',', '.') . "</p>";
                echo "<p>Condición: " . $row["condicion"] . "</p>";
                echo "<hr>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<h2>No se encontraron resultados</h2>";
        }

        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        echo "Error en la consulta";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Es difícil ya que no se cuenta con todo el escenario para replicar tu caso. Yo te aconsejaría que depuraras por partes. Primero, depura la consulta en la DB, si funciona en tu DBM entonces ve parte por parte en PHP, viendo el resultado que te arroja y así hasta llegar al problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que no se están enlazando correctamente las variables contra sus placeholders en las diversas situaciones, por ejemplo:

**[ Caso 1 ]**
Si el campo de búsqueda `$_GET['s']` está vacio, y `$region = 'all'` tendrás esta consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE precio BETWEEN ? AND ? AND condicion = ?
```

pero en `bind_param`:

```
("iiss", $minPrice, $maxPrice, $condition, $region);
```

Como podrás notar, hay un término de más.

**[ Caso 2 ]**
Si en el campo de búsqueda `$_GET['s']` hay un término, y `$region = 'all'` entonces tendrás esto:

```
SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE precio BETWEEN ? AND ? 
AND condicion = ? AND (titulo LIKE ? OR descripcion LIKE ?)
```

Y en `bind_param` esto otro:

```
("iisss", $minPrice, $maxPrice, $condition, $region, $searchTerm);
```

Coinciden los términos, pero `$region` no tiene nada que hacer en esa consulta. Debería estar 2 veces `$searchTerm` ya que estás buscando por **título** o por **descripción**.

**[ Caso 3 ]**
Si `$region != 'all'`, pero está dentro del array `$regiones`, y hay un término de búsqueda en `$_GET['s']`, la consulta SQL exigirá **6 parámetros**. No tienes una condición así en ninguna parte del código.

---

En otras palabras, está mal la lógica, porque no estás considerando todas las posibilidades.
Sugiero intentes resolver esto de una forma más dinámica, como el siguiente ejemplo. Dejo marcados con `<-- *` los cambios propuestos.

```php
    // ...
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE precio BETWEEN ? AND ? AND condicion = ?";
    $params = array('iis', [$minPrice, $maxPrice, $condition]); // <-- * Nuevo

    if ($region != "all") {
        $sql .= " AND id_region = (SELECT id FROM Regiones WHERE nombre = ?)";
        $params[0] .= 's'; // <-- *
        array_push($params[1], $region); // <-- *
    }

    if ($orderBy == "mayor-precio") {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY precio DESC";
    } elseif ($orderBy == "menor-precio") {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY precio ASC";
    }

    if (!empty($searchTerm)) {
        $searchTerm = "%$searchTerm%";
        $sql .= " AND (titulo LIKE ? OR descripcion LIKE ?)";
        $params[0] .= 'ss'; // <-- *
        array_push($params[1], $searchTerm, $searchTerm); // <-- *
    }
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param($params[0], ...$params[1]); // <-- *
        // Ya no es necesario el if (!empty($searchTerm))
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        // ... Pintar los resultados
        // ...
    } else {
        echo "Error en la consulta";
    }
// ...
```

Comment: muchas gracias! me sacó un dolor de cabeza :)